# standard frameworks for testing java statistical based module

Tags: java, testing, statistics, integration-testing

I'm creating a module in java which takes some samples over time and deduces some deducations.  just a standard statistical model.

now in order to test it i need to generate some samples over time, and change them, and verify the results.. over time, and be able to assert that results match the varying samples over time, and change some base parameters run the same simualtions.

now instead of building such complex test cases by myself i was trying to search if there is already such a test library for java which can reduce the workload on such test cases, i couldn't really find one... anyone aware of such a library? (if not for best practices?)

thanks

Comment: Unit/integration tests and sample data sound like the perfect fit for this.  Is there any reason you're not setting up your environment and asserting that what you put in is what you expected out?

Comment: the reason is i seem not to be able to just call methods and assert return values.

Comment: problem is that what i put in is very complex (and also out).  I need to generate many values as input data (based on a behavior i expect) and the output changes as the input changes (as input is generated over into the system, there should be lot of input which will simulate many users) and users behaviour is effected back by system response and i need to simulate and assert all that.  so it sounds like i need to create a framework for simulation and assertion. before building such a framework iw as sure maybe something exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [Apache Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/random.html). There are many classes for statistics and they have unit tests which have data. There is also a class for generating random data:

> The Commons Math random package includes utilities for
>
> ```
> generating random numbers
> generating random vectors
> generating random strings
> generating cryptographically secure sequences of random numbers or strings
> generating random samples and permutations
> analyzing distributions of values in an input file and generating values "like" the values in the file
> generating data for grouped frequency distributions or histograms
> ```
>
> The source of random data used by the data generation utilities is
>   pluggable. By default, the JDK-supplied PseudoRandom Number Generator
>   (PRNG) is used, but alternative generators can be "plugged in" using
>   an adaptor framework, which provides a generic facility for replacing
>   java.util.Random with an alternative PRNG. Other very good PRNG
>   suitable for Monte-Carlo analysis (but not for cryptography) provided
>   by the library are the Mersenne twister from Makoto Matsumoto and
>   Takuji Nishimura and the more recent WELL generators (Well
>   Equidistributed Long-period Linear) from François Panneton, Pierre
>   L'Ecuyer and Makoto Matsumoto.
>
> Sections 2.2-2.6 below show how to use the commons math API to
>   generate different kinds of random data. The examples all use the
>   default JDK-supplied PRNG. PRNG pluggability is covered in 2.7. The
>   only modification required to the examples to use alternative PRNGs is
>   to replace the argumentless constructor calls with invocations
>   including a RandomGenerator instance as a parameter.